# What does the phrase "About one stone" in response to the question "How have you changed over the years" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Googling it didn't seem to lend any results except the unrelated killing two birds, etc, stuff.

Edit: In Berkshire Hathaway's 1995 [annual meeting](https://buffett.cnbc.com/video/1995/05/01/afternoon-session---1995-berkshire-hathaway-annual-meeting.html) at 1:04:54 (or second occurence of the word "stone" if you search page text on the transcript and click on the phrase to jump to the timestamp. Charlie says in response to an audience member regarding "Warren changing over the years" "I'd say about one stone", which is meant as a joke. I guess, like the first answer says, it probably jokingly mentions weight or something like that.

Comment: Where (in the world) did you hear this?

Comment: @KillingTime I updated the question to answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably the speaker has put on a stone (14 lb, or something over 6 kg) in weight.

Comment: Alternatively they might have _lost_ about 14lbs. It must be a British response though because the Americans just count weight in pounds up to up to a quarter of a US ton and the rest of the world is sensible and uses kilogrammes.

Comment: Oh, I guess this might have been used as a joke.

Comment: I guess I will accept this, this seems to make some sense